# Using RegEx to search and replace a number in a Notepad++ selection

Tags: regex, notepad++

I just learned about regex and it's still quite confusing to me.

For a start, I'm having a file in Notepad++ with 500k lines.
At about line 394900 is some static content that needs to be replaced. It's not that much to do manually, but just for learning purpusses I'd like to do this via RegEx.

The lines contain the following strings while X is a RandomNumber: {x 0.xxxxx xx.xxx}
Now I have to replace the second number of each line before the .xxxxx

So to make it short: {x 0.xxxxx xx.xxx} has to be replaced with {x 8.xxxxx xx.xxx} in each line.

What would be the easiest way to do this via regex?

Comment: is .xxxxx fixed 5 digits followed by space?

Comment: try this http://markantoniou.blogspot.com/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html

Comment: Please include what you have tried. Since you just learned about regex, it is even more important to know what you understand and what you don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead based regex like below,

```
\d+(?=\.\d{5}\s)
```

Then replace the matched number with `8` . It matches the number only if it's followed by a dot then a 5 digit number and a space.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rF1sU7/6)

Comment: thanks. that did the trick.
also big thanks for the URL to the regex101 site. It's even explaining how it all works. that surely will help me a lot in the future to understand regex :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `\d` to represent a digit:

Replace `(\{\d )\d(\.\d{5} \d{2}\.\d{3}\})`

with `\18\2` (first group, then the digit `8`, followed by the second group).

If explicit quantifiers (e.g. `\d{3}`) are not supported, use `\d+` instead (i.e. one or more digits):

**Without explicit quantifiers (for Npp version < 6):**

Replace `(\{\d )\d(\.\d+ \d+\.\d+\})` with `\18\2`.

Comment: i think this `\d(\.\d{5} )` would be enough.